# What and where is the DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature in my Azure Notification Hub

Tags: c#, azure-notificationhub

I am following the tutorial [on here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-aspnet-backend-ios-apple-apns-notification) by microsoft on setting up a notification hub for an iOS app. The "Test Send" section of Notification Hub succeeds in sending the notification, and I actually receive it on my registered device.

However, when I invoke an notification from my C# backend, nothing happens. I even get `HttpStatusCode.OK` after invoking `SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync`.

So the Azure Hub setup in Azure portal seems to be fine since the test send works, but my backend is probably wrong somewhere.

On the code below:

```
private Notifications() {
    Hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(
        "<your hub's DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature>",
        "<hub name>");
}
```

What exactly is `DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature`, and which part of my connection string do I get that?

At the moment here is what I have:

```
    Hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(
            "Endpoint=sb://myappnotificationsns.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=somerandomcharacterhere27374+7384bvbher38434fve0=",
            "myappnotifications"
                );
```

**nb**: thats a fake connection string.

Is this correct or wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so turns out the above setup is correct.

My issue instead was that the username passed during token registration was null. There is no exception or error from the SDK for some reason. Had to hunt furiously to find the issue.

Hope this helps someone someday.